# Corona SDK and level-based game architecture

Tags: architecture, lua, coronasdk, 2d-games

I'm new in game development.

From my experience I know that all reusable elements should me moved to one place. So, if I want to make my game scalable and manage gameplay in one class, I need to move all gameplay code to one lua file and create separate descriptors per each level.

But what is the best practice in Corona SDK and Lua language? Should I have some resource file that contains description about each level, or should I use scene files?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if its best practice, but for my game I used the Corona Composer. I had a few main "scene" for various parts of my game ( I had a main game.lua scene, a dialogue.lua, a quiz.lua scene and so on...). For my various levels I just simply used level data files (which were just big lua tables) to store all the relevant data about each level (platforms, enemies, collectibles). Then at the beginning of each level I simply loaded in the level and accessed the required data from the lua table.

From memory I started with this template (http://www.tandgapps.co.uk/downloads/mario-platformer-template/), adopted a similar structure and went from there.